# Same loop giving different output. Java IO

Tags: java

I am facing a very strange problem where the same loop keeps giving me different different output on change of value of BUFFER

```
  final int BUFFER = 100;
        char[] charArr = new char[BUFFER];
        StringBuffer objStringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (objBufferedReader.read(charArr, 0,BUFFER) != -1) {
            objStringBuffer.append(charArr);
        }
 objFileWriter.write(objStringBuffer.toString());
```

When i change BUFFER size to 500 it gives me a file of 7 kb when i change BUFFER size to 100000 it gives a file of 400 kb where the contents are repeated again and again. Please help. What should i do to prevent this?

Comment: `BUFFER` is a misleading name for a variable that specifies the buffer **size**. You should probably call it `BUFFER_SIZE`.

Comment: Your code does not seems to be complete. How is defined objBufferedReader ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **must** remember the return value of the `read()` call, because `read` does **not** guarantee that the entire buffer has been filled.

You will need to remember that value and use it in the append call to only append that many characters.

Otherwise you'll append un-initialized characters to the `StringBuffer` that didn't actually come from the `Reader` (probably either `0` or values written by previous `read()` calls).

Comment: There's a StringBuffer function for this purpose:
append(char str[], int offset, int len)
And you should use StringBuilder by the way, if synchronization isn't required.

Comment: Great job! Thanks Joachim. That was real quick

Comment: Ok tiger! Thanks for extra advise. I will change it to StringBuilder. I don't require any synchronization.